# CQ5 richtext 'ENTER' key event inserts <p> tag on every line

Tags: extjs, aem

To override the 'ENTER' key event behavior to **NOT** to add `<p></p>` tag for each line of text, code in KeyPlugin.js has to be changed in the following block

`// handle ENTER key
        this.mustEnsureBlocks = false;
        if (e.isEnter() && !cancelKey) {`

keyPlugin.js located at /libs/cq/ui/rte/core/plugins/KeyPlugin.js .

Does anyone tell me, how to overlay/override the block of code.

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy file from `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/plugins/KeyPlugin.js` to `/apps/cq/ui/rte/core/plugins/KeyPlugin.js` and override necessary block of code(wich responsible for inserting of paragraphs)

Or you are able to add listener to yours component wich will deletes `<p></p>` tags:

**JavaScript way**:

Write the following function:

```
function removeUnecessartyTagsFromMyComponent(field) {
    var value = field.getValue();
    var pOpend = /<p[^>]*>/g;
    var pClosed = /<\/p>/g;
    var correctValue = value.replace(pOpend, "").replace(pClosed, "");
    if (value != correctValue) {
        field.setValue(correctValue);
    }
}
```

And use it in yours dialog:

```
<photoBy
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./myComponent"
    title="My Copmonent"
    fieldLabel="Enter text"
    xtype="richtext">
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
              valid="function(field)removeUnecessartyTagsFromMyComponent(field);}"/>
</photoBy>
```

Please be noticed - you may use another listener instead of **valid** see more at [CQ Widget API doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.RichText)

Comment: could you please tell me more about listener to delete <p></p> tags. Thank you!